# War horse in normal Red Dead Redemption?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

I really want to get the War Horse in Red Dead Redemption, but i already went out and bought the two seperate games: Red Dead Redemption and Undead Nightmare. Is there a way to get the War Horse (Not the fire one) in the normal Red Dead game???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two "War Horses" in Red Dead Redemption, and each is specific to a particular half of the game:

In the base game, the "[War Horse](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/War_Horse)" (a horse used in war) is a pre-order bonus that was later added as paid DLC.  It is also included as part of the "Game of the Year Edition."  If you have the War Horse, the deed will be in your inventory.  It's one of the best horses in the game, and having the deed means you can call a new one whenever your horse dies.

If you don't have this DLC, you can come darn close to the War Horse by breaking the [Kentucky Saddler](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Kentucky_Saddler) or the [American Standardbred](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/American_Standardbred).  While the War Horse is better, I don't know that it's *$1 extra* better.

In the Undead Nightmare expansion, you can find the horse [War](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/War_%28horse%29), which is one of the Four Horses of the Apocalypse.  It must be found and broken in-game in order to use it.  You won't get the "deed" to this horse until after you've completed the ambient challenge related to these horses.  It is on fire, and it burns things that it touches.

Just for reference, you can't get the horse War in the base game, and you also can't get the War Horse in Undead Nightmare.

Comment: Thankyou :) So i need to buy the game of the year edition to get the War horse?

Comment: @TazFlame, you can also buy it as separate DLC in the Xbox Live or PSN store.  I think it costs $1.